# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to install laravel passport in my blog by using this command

> composer require laravel/passport

but at the time of installing i face some fatal error like this

> **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/Users/Hamid/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Dependen
> cyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
> **
> some one please tell me the answer how i fix it

Comment: run `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require laravel/passport` it will work

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that, you could use

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 C:/Users/Hamid/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar require laravel/passport
```